# Change number of rows shown in GridView in Yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2

I'm trying to change the amount of rows shown on the gridView (Yii2) but I couldn't find anything in their documentation.

Is it even possible or do I have to have to use another extension? (Kartik for example.)

Also, is it possible to remove 
**"Showing x of x items"** as shown beneath?

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To change the number of items displayed per page, you need to set `pagination` in your data provider.

Example:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    ...
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 10,
    ],
]);
```

As for removing information about displayed items you need to remove `summary` from `layout`:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    ...
    'layout' => "{items}\n{pager}",
]) ?>
```

**Official docs:**

- [BaseDataProvider $pagination](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-basedataprovider.html#$pagination-detail)
- [Pagination $pageSize](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-pagination.html#$pageSize-detail)
- [GridView $layout](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html#$layout-detail)

Comment: Perfect, going to try it out now. Pretty sure it's going to work. Thanks!

Comment: can I use this too into kartik's gridview?

Comment: @BlackSkull I believe you can.

Answer (score 8):

or like that

```
public function actionIndex() {
 $searchModel = new SettingSearch();
 $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
 $dataProvider->pagination = ['pageSize' => 100];

 return $this->render('index', [
  'searchModel' => $searchModel,
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
  ]);
}
```

Comment: or simply $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize = 100;